# Oracle ADF: View criteria is not working in 12c

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

Hello I am developing a web application using Oracle ADF. Am using jdeveloper12c. I have created a view criteria for a view object as shown below in 12c.

[image]

After creating the view criteria am trying to drop this onto a a.jsf page as a ADF Query Panel. When I am trying to run this page I am getting the following error.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
    oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:192)
    oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:105)

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groovy/control/customizers/CompilationCustomizer
    oracle.jbo.ExprEval$ScriptLibrary.createShell(ExprEval.java:2534)
    oracle.jbo.ExprEval$ScriptLibrary.getShell(ExprEval.java:2475)
    oracle.jbo.ExprEval.parseScript(ExprEval.java:1571)
    oracle.jbo.ExprEval.findScript(ExprEval.java:1152)
    oracle.jbo.ExprEval.doEvaluate(ExprEval.java:1956)
    oracle.jbo.ExprEval.doEvaluate(ExprEval.java:1928)
```

root cause

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.customizers.CompilationCustomizer
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    oracle.jbo.ExprEval$ScriptLibrary.createShell(ExprEval.java:2534)
    oracle.jbo.ExprEval$ScriptLibrary.getShell(ExprEval.java:2475)
    oracle.jbo.ExprEval.parseScript(ExprEval.java:1571)
    oracle.jbo.ExprEval.findScript(ExprEval.java:1152)
    oracle.jbo.ExprEval.doEvaluate(ExprEval.java:1956)
    oracle.jbo.ExprEval.doEvaluate(ExprEval.java:1928)
```

I have successfully created view criteria and used in jdeveloper11.1.2.4.

Please help me with this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your  View Object and View Criteria from BC Tester?

Comment: Florin Marcus - Yes I have tested from BC Tester . It is working fine.

Comment: I know for a fact that af:queries / view criterias work in 12c, so is something related to your code.  Do a bit of experimenting: create a new Jdev workspace using HR schema, re-create the same scenario on a simple environment.

Comment: Thank you florin marcus. Let me check and get back to you. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hi. Marcus. The view criteria is successfully running on Integrated weblogic  server. But it is giving the following exception when am trying to run this on Tomcat 6.x

Comment: SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.customizers.CompilationCustomizer
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)

Answer (score 0):

According to compatibility matrix, you need Tomcat 7 for running ADF 12c applications:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/documentation/1212-cert-1964670.html

Comment: Did you install the ADF Essentials libraries on your tomcat? Seems like you are missing the groovy libraries.

Comment: Thanks for you help all of you. Thank you very much. After some R&D I am able to see search criteria in my page. But searching is not happening. Means when am clicking on Search button after entering some data in view criteria nothing is happening. When am clicking on reset button. All the values are cleared. In logs also no error.                                                                                 Please help me. Please.

Comment: I don't have enough experience with ADF Essentials and Tomcat, but if you prepare a sample application running on HR schema where you can reproduce this problem, I will be more than happy to fill in an Service Request with Oracle in your behalf.